# bazel: How do you "request" that a cc_binary build the stripped version of the binary?

Tags: bazel

The docs for Bazel's [`cc_binary` rule](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary) say:

> Implicit output targets
>
> > `<name>.stripped` (only built if explicitly requested): A stripped version of the binary. `strip -g` is run on the binary to remove debug symbols. Additional strip options can be provided on the command line using `--stripopt=-foo`. This output is only built if explicitly requested.

How do I "explicitly request" that this stripped binary get built? Is there something I need to put in my `cc_binary` declaration in my `BUILD` file? I can't figure it out from the docs (or the Bazel source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I think I figured out how.

If my `BUILD` file has this:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "mytool",
  srcs = ["mytool.c"]
)
```

... then from the command line I can build the stripped binary with this:

```
bazel build //:mytool.stripped
```

or, the more common scenario, if I have another BUILD rule that needs the stripped binary as one of its inputs, I can just refer to it by that same label, `:mytool.stripped`. Here is sort of a weird contrived example:

```
genrule(
  name = "mygenrule",
  outs = ["genrule.out"],
  srcs = [":tool1.stripped"],
  # run tool1.stripped, sends its output to genrule.out:
  cmd = "$(SRCS) > $@"
)
```